# C# Console Selenium | Read lines from text file

Tags: c#, selenium

I have created a c# console application using **Selenium** with Chrome Drivers. 
This is something that i am wondering if i can have some help on. 
Essentially i want to create something where there will be a **emails.txt** file and within that file the user places an email (example) **example@gmail.com** and they then make a new line with another email **example2@gmail.com**. So on....Basically once they have added that within the **emails.txt** on the website i am automating there is an email field. I am wondering if i can make it so that on the **first line** of emails it will run the first auto form filling, then on the **second line** of emails it will open a brand new **driver window** and doing the same thing.

I could not find anything like this as such on the internet so some help and direction would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a `Form` class that represents the form you want to fill:

```
public class Form
{
  private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

  public Form(IWebDriver driver)
  {
     _driver = driver;
  }

  public void Fill(string email)
  {
    // this is where you use the driver to access the form fields and set their contents
  }
}
```

Then there's the `Main` method that reads the emails from file, creates new forms and fills them with the emails:

```
public static void Main()
{
   var emails = File.ReadAllLines("emails.txt");
   foreach (var email in emails)
   {
     using (var driver = ... )// todo create new chrome driver instance
     {
        // todo use the driver to navigate to the page where the form is
        var form = new Form(driver);
        form.Fill(email);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Alright so basically. Does the code represent counting each line within the emails.txt. Then once one line has been counted it will use another chrome driver?

Comment: **using (var driver = ....)** what exactly would take place here? The URL of the driver?

Comment: this is what i have currently added. I seem to get errors from the drivers. Any way to fix these. And can you confirm i have done this part correctly. Screenshot - [link](https://i.imgur.com/F60IkKU.png)

Comment: It should work after you get it to compile **by yourself**.

Comment: I got the error solved by adding a new ChromeDriver instance: Could you tell me if this is the correct contents to add below the **public void Fill(string email)** - driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys(email); Currently it works by asking for the email address then when the user inputs the email it reads the line by doing **string email = Console.ReadLine();** so how should i go about doing this part?